# What is the purpose of indirect checkpoint when the default checkpoint time (when recovery time is 0) does a 1 minute checkpoint?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, checkpoint

Indirect checkpoint is performed when the target recovery time is configured.

When the value is 0, then it will do checkpoints such that default recovery time is 1 minute.

Where as if the value is greater than 0 (recommended value is 60), then SQL server will do indirect checkpoints. I'm trying to understand menaing of indirect checkpoint with an example - Suppose value of 40 is configured, then does it mean that:

- SQL server does checkpoint so that recovery time is 40 seconds?

Then what is the difference between automatic and indirect checkpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let us clear up a misunderstanding:

> When the value is 0, then it will do checkpoints every minute.

No, that is not how the `sp_configure` setting works. The setting specifies the amount of time you want to wait for the REDO part of the recovery process. This means that the interval between checkpoint will vary to a high degree.

The database setting works the same way, how long you want to wait for the REDO part.

The difference is in the implementation between the two. The `sp_configure` setting is based on number of log records and the database setting is based on number of dirty pages.

This is all documented in [Database checkpoints (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/database-checkpoints-sql-server).

Comment: So if value is 0 then recovery time is 60 seconds by default?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Unless overridden by the database setting.

Comment: So leaving the value to 0 is same as setting the value to 60?

Comment: Yes, see the table in that article: 0 means "automatic checkpoints whose target recovery interval is 1 minute."